# Composition build function from two other functions

Tags: typescript

I am not happy with TypeScript overloading things can get very complicated. I am looking for a way to "overload" compositionally from two separate functions. Is it possible to merge these two functions below via with one function that has the ability to take the same arguments passed? Where the Types are all in order.

```
function fromFileQuery (a: FileQuery): FileQuery {
    if (!a.path) throw new Error('missing path');
    return {
        path: a.path,
        encoding: a.encoding || null,
        flag: a.flag || FileSystemFlags.R
    };
}

function fromFilePathOptions (...args: FilePathOptions): FileQuery {
    const [path, fileQuery] = args;
    return fromFileQuery({...fileQuery, path});
}

const getFileQuery = make([fromFileQuery, fromFilePathOptions])
```

Where `getFileQuery` supports a `FileQuery` or `FilePathOptions`.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
type ArgumentTypes<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

function make(fns: any[]): Function {
    type input = ArgumentTypes<typeof fns[0]>;
    type output = ReturnType<typeof fns[0]>;
    return (...arg: input): output => {

    }
}

const x = make([fromFileQuery, fromFilePathOptions]);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `make`? Is it a composition of function? Maybe you can check `compose` or `pipe` of ramda

Comment: @mickaelw yeah the idea is that it would create a new function which would be a switch between `fromFileQuery` and `fromFilePathOptions`  and a union of the `input` and `return types`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the types to workout in this case is not particularly hard in this case.

We firstly need to capture all function types. This is best done using [tuples in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897). Then we need to get all the parameter types and all the return types of the functions. We can do this since 3.1 using [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063).

```
type AllParameters<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[])=> any ? Parameters<T[P]> : never }
type AllReturnTypes<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[])=> any ? ReturnType<T[P]> : never }
function make<T extends Array<(...a: any[])=> any>>(...fns: T){
    return (...arg: AllParameters<T>[number]): AllReturnTypes<T>[number] => {
        for(var fn of fns){
            if(fn.length === arg.length) {
                return fn(...arg);
            }
        }
        throw new Error("Not supported")
    }
}

function fromFileQuery (a: FileQuery): FileQuery {
    if (!a.path) throw new Error('missing path');
    return {
        path: a.path,
        encoding: a.encoding || null,
        flag: a.flag || FileSystemFlags.R
    };
}

function fromFilePathOptions (path: string, fileQuery: FileQuery): FileQuery {
    return fromFileQuery({...fileQuery, path});
}

const getFileQuery = make(fromFileQuery, fromFilePathOptions)

const x = make(fromFileQuery, fromFilePathOptions);

x({
    flag: "",
    encoding: "",
    path: ""
});

x("", {
    flag: "",
    encoding: ""
})
```

The more difficult part is deciding which function to call. In the example above I chose to use `fn.length === arg.length` so select which function to call. This obviously might not be the best solution in all cases. We might consider also adding an extra function to decide which function to call.

Hope this helps, let me know if I can help with anything else, feedback is appreciated :)